# How can I make one table depend on another in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have the following tables that I created in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Application] (
    [Id]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Application] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Account] (
    [Id]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Account] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Is there a way I can change these so that there's a link to the 
account table inside the application table. A link that makes it
not possible to delete an application entry if there is an 
account for that application?  Sorry if this is a basic question
but I only know how to use the designer and I am not sure how I 
can code this in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a foreign key relationship between the two tables.  In your case you would want to add another int type column to the Account table called Application_Id.  Then add the foreign relationship between Application_Id and Id on the Application table.  I also suggest possibly changing Id on the Application table to Application_Id

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Application] (
    [Application_Id]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Application] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Application_Id] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Account] (
    [Id]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Application_Id] INT,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Account] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT fk_AccountApps FOREIGN KEY (Application_Id)
    REFERENCES Application(Application_Id)
);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c4917)

[W3 Schools Foreign Key](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c4917)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved using foreign key concept.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key